# Unable to get bloblist from a subdirectory in Storage Account

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage-account

I would like to list all blobs from a subdirectory for example `images/nature` in a storage account. I am using this c# code to achieve my aim:

```
string storageConnectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("BlobConnection", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnectionString);
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(@"images/nature");
```

This code doesn't work for me. Do you have any idea, how can I do this job?

Following code works fine if all blobs are in root folder:

```
 string storageConnectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("BlobConnection", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
 CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnectionString);
 CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
 CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(@"images");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following code:

```
string storageConnectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("BlobConnection", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnectionString);
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(@"images");
var blobs = container.ListBlobs("nature", true);
```

This should list blobs inside "nature" folder and all folders beneath that.

Essentially the issue was with the following line of code:

```
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(@"images/nature");
```

Azure Blob Storage basically has 2 level hierarchy - container and blobs. The folders there are virtual and essentially prefix that you put in a blob's name.

What I have done in my code is listing the blobs from the container the name of which starts with a prefix ("nature" in your example).